# Using 'as' prop for Link element in Next.js leads to 404 and refresh

Tags: reactjs, next.js

So I'm following along a tutorial and it's a very short video on the 'as' prop in next js. Seems simple. Add an 'as' prop and your Link element will route to the href in the link but will have the 'as' prop contents in the browser bar.

My code worked just fine before, but when I added 'as' for the link below, I got a 404. Browser console output showed that an attempt at a GET request was made... for the link in the 'as' prop.

Why is that? Isn't that the opposite of what it's meant to do? Why is my code trying to GET the contents of the 'as' prop instead of the 'href' prop?

For what it's worth, the instructor is using getInitialProps and I'm using getServerSide props (for both the index shown below and the post that it leads to). But I don't see why that would cause a GET to the 'as' prop, and also cause a refresh.

In the course it's highlighted that this will cause a 404 for a refresh, but it should work just fine if used without refreshing.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Link from 'next/link';

const Index = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Our index page!!!</h1>
      {posts.map(post => (
        <li key={post.id}>
          <Link href={`/post?id=${post.id}`} as={`/p/${post.id}`}>
            <a>{post.title}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const res = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  const {data} = res;
  return {
    props: { posts: data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}

export default Index;
```

Here is the code for the component it renders:

```
import { withRouter } from 'next/router';
import axios from 'axios';

const Post = ({ id, comments }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Comments for Post #{id}</h1>
      {comments.map(comment => (
        <Comment key={comment.id} {...comment}/>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

const Comment = ({ email, body }) => (
  <div>
    <h5>{email}</h5>
    <p>{body}</p>
  </div>
);

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { query } = context;
  const res = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=${query.id}`);
  return {
    props: { ...query, comments: res.data }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}

export default withRouter(Post);
```

Thank you.

Output:

[Console output shows a GET request to the link specified in the 'as' prop! Why!?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKsAT.png)

Comment: What is `Link`? A custom component? `Link` from react-router-dom? Something else?

Comment: @DrewReese my apologies. It's the Link component from Next Js. Edited to add the imports for clarifictation.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the other way around. The `href` prop should be the system path of the page component you're linking to. It's not a dynamic value that changes at runtime.

And the `as` prop is the path that the browser requests (as shown in the URL bar).

This is the correct usage:

```
<Link href={`/post/[pid]`} as={`/post?id=${post.id}`}>
  <a>{post.title}</a>
</Link>
```

This assumes your page component is stored at `/pages/post/[pid]`. If you've stored the `Post` component at `/pages/Post.js`, move it to `/pages/post/[pid]`.

**Update based on your new comment:**

If you instead want the page URLs to be `/p/1`, `/p/2` etc. you can do the following:

Create a Page component at `pages/p/[pid].js`. Include `getServerSideProps`:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { params } = context;
  const res = await axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments?postId=${params.pid}`);
  return {
    props: { id: params.pid, comments: res.data }, // Will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

In your `Index` component, use the `Link` component like this (assuming you haven't made any other changes to the component):

```js
      {posts.map(post => (
        <li key={post.id}>
          <Link href="/p/[pid]" as={`/p/${post.id}`}>
            <a>{post.title}</a>
          </Link>
        </li>
      ))}
```

Next.js uses a file-based router, and the links have to match the component path. You can't put whatever you want in the `as` prop.

Comment: Thank you for the input. My page component is at '/post', and the id is passed in as a parameter that's extracted. I might be misunderstanding the 'as' prop, but I'd like it to overwrite the default link on the browser. So say I want to access /post/id=2, I'd instead like the browser to show '/p/2'. I have no routes set up for '/p/2' in any way, just the instructor was able to make the browser bar show anything he wanted with 'as', like he used '/doggie' in 'as' as an example and it worked

Comment: By the way, @SerdarHalac, Next.js uses a file-based router, so the links have to match the component path. You can't put whatever you want in the `as` prop. I updated my answer to reflect your new comment (please check again, as the previous edit contained some errors in the code).

Comment: I see. So basically the idea to use 'as' as a sort of 'url masker' and put in whatever you want to replace the original link with IS NOT it's purpose. That does help. I think the tutorial actually was unintentionally misleading and may have exploited a pre-update bug? Either way thank you for the update.

Comment: Hey so I tried your solution, renamed my post.js to /p/[pid].js (which just created  [pid].js inside of a 'p' folder, changing code to yours, and I'm getting the same issue: GET http://localhost:3000/p/1 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Pages should reside in a `pages` folder: `/pages/p/[pid].js`. Did you try that? I tried running the code on my local machine, and it worked perfectly. (However, there seems to be some problems with the public API you're using: the request often times out when I try to fetch a comment, but this is unrelated to your original problem.)